# O que significa if(variavél){ /*ação*/}?

Tags: javascript, if

Ao colocar **somente** a *variavél* dentro do `if`, **por exemplo**

`if( variavél ){ /*ação*/}`

O que significa esse `if`?

E ao *contrário*

`if( !variavél ){ /*ação*/}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Estruturas de comparação como o `if` esperam valores booleanos (VERDADEIRO, FALSO). Mas com a evolução das linguagens o conceito de o que é verdadeiro ou falso foi ampliado. então vamos dar um exemplo

```js
var teste = false;
if(teste == true){
  alert('Sou verdadeiro');
}
else{
  alert('Sou falso');
}
```

Podemos ver que claramente a variável `teste` é falsa portando vai imprimir `sou falso`.

Mas podemos ocultar o valor a ser comparado, já que a variável `teste` já é um valor booleano. Portando o código funcionaria mesmo escrito dessa forma:

```js
var teste = false;
if(teste){
  alert('Sou verdadeiro');
}
else{
  alert('Sou falso');
}
```

Dito isso, podemos verificar que o Javascript (e diversas outras linguagens) consideram como falsas os seguintes casos:

1. valor Indefinido
2. Nulo
3. Boolean false
4. Número zero (0)
5. String de comprimento zero (String vazia)

Qualquer coisa que não seja esses exemplos é considerado verdadeiro, portando se eu fazer o seguinte código

```js
var teste = 12;
if(teste){
  alert('Sou Verdadeiro');
}
else{
  alert('Sou Falso');
}
```

A variável `teste` é considerada verdadeira por que foi iniciada com um valor diferente de zero.

Agora em relação ao operador `!` que vem antes de uma comparação dentro do `if`, ele simplismente inverte o valor de comparação. Se formos comparar um valor que é verdadeiro, ele inverte para falso.

Comment: Adendo: Você também pode usar a `tabela verdade` para estudar como funciona a estrutura condicional `if..else`.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do [Phelipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99543/phelipe) está correta, trata-se da técnica de *shorthand*, onde:

`if(variavel)` retorna *true* nos casos onde a variável `variavel`:

- não é `null` (tem algum valor)
- é diferente de `0` (número, não string).
- é diferente de vazio (<kbd>espaço</kbd> não é vazio)
- é `true` (`variavel = true;`)

No caso de `(!variavel)` retorna *false* onde a `variavel`:

- é `null` (não tem valor definido)
- é vazio (`variavel = "";`)
- é `false` (`variavel = false;`)
- é igual a `0` (número, não string)

[**Neste link**](https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/) você pode aprender outras técnicas de escrever de forma curta alguns códigos JavaScript.